# toad for oracle - perform queries during the debugging/execution

Tags: database, oracle, toad

I am a new "Toad for Oracle Pro" user. I have a package on oracle, which takes about 10 minutes. I insert some log/trace messages into a table during the process.

So, when I execute my package I cannot perform a seperate query to a table. Simply I want to check the log table during the execution.

During the execution of a database process toad locks itself. It does not allow me to do anything else. After the execution terminated I can perform my queries.

I want to execute queries during the execution with toad. This is available in SQL*Developer - which is free.

Can I configure toad to do that?

toad version; 11.6.1

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally just open two instances of TOAD. I don't know if there's a better way, but I've certainly not found one.

Comment: I also open two editors on an instance of toad, i execute my package from one, from the other one i check the log tables.